# Problem with partitioning non-clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server-2016, partitioning

I have a database with partition function defined. Over this partition function there are 2 schemes defined, one for Data files and one for Indexes files.
Data and index files are divided quaterly (2017Q4, 2018Q1, 2018Q2, 2018Q3, 2018Q4, 2019Q1, 2019Q2, Future)

Lately I have noticed that my index file Future is growing when there should not be any data in it.

Using Kendra Little script:

- [Which Filegroup is that Partition Using? How Many Rows Does It Have?](https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/31/which-filegroup-is-that-partition-using-how-many-rows-does-it-have/)

I've checked how many rows are in each file/filegroup.

And up to 2018Q2 everything seems to be working fine.
There are the same number of rows in 2017Q4Data and 2017Q4Index file, 2018Q1Data and 2018Q1Index file, 2018Q2Data and 2018Q2Index file.

However starting with 2018Q3 - data files are filled up correctly, but all index data is going to FutureIndex file.

[image: Result of Kendra Little's script]

What could be the problem here?

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PFEReceipt](int) 
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (
520171231, 520180331, 520180630, 520180930, 520181231, 520190331, 520190630, 599999999)
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PSEReceiptData] AS PARTITION [PFEReceipt] TO (
[FG_Data2017Q4], [FG_Data2018Q1], [FG_Data2018Q2], [FG_Data2018Q3], [FG_Data2018Q4], [FG_Data2019Q1], [FG_Data2019Q2], [FG_DataFuture], 
[FG_UpperDataNone])
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PSEReceiptIndex] AS PARTITION [PFEReceipt] TO (
[FG_Index2017Q4], [FG_Index2018Q1], [FG_Index2018Q2], [FG_Index2018Q3], [FG_Index2018Q4], [FG_Index2019Q1], [FG_Index2019Q2], [FG_IndexFuture], 
[FG_UpperIndexNone])
GO
```

Comment: can you show us your check constraints?

Comment: Add the partition function and scheme DDL to your question.

Comment: Are data and index partitioned using the same column? If not, that will explain your symptoms.

Comment: Yes, it is using the same column

Comment: Rebuilding those indexes solved the issue. However still looking for the root cause of the problem.